# abstract algebra 2 - two group isomorphic - prove

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-isomorphism

I am a student in computer science - first year. I study linear linear algebra 2 - course of linear algebra 1. - In some institutions academic studies teach the courses together / teach in another way.

I tried to solve the question a few hours but I'm not sure how to solve it exactly.

the question is:

"
3. Consider U14 and U18. Are they isomorphic? Prove (find an isomorphism function) or
disprove (find a reason why they cannot be).
Remarks:
(a) The set of integers of the group Un is the set of numbers from 1 to n − 1 which
are relatively prime to n. For example, in U8 it is the set {1, 3, 5, 7}, in U12 it is the
set {1, 5, 7, 11}, in U24 it is the set {1, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23}. When n is prime, it
1
is the set {1, 2, . . . , p − 1}. The operation is product modulo the n indicated as a
subscript – that is, in the examples above – the 8 or 12 or 24.
(b) In many textbooks, you may find the groups Un written as U(n).

"

At first glance - you can think it is not isomorphic - because u14 - include only 5 prime which complement 14:
1+13 = 14
3+11 = 14
7 + 7 = 14 - whice i think its bad assume.

i think about the option 5 + 9 = 14
but 14 it not prime...

u17 include 6 primes - they do not have the same amount of organs - so they are not isomorphic

Am I right? And how do I prove it?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Check cardinality of each set and remember that the two sets have finite cardinality..

I just read your bottom line. Yes, just prove that if two sets are isomorphic and of finite cardinality, then they must have the same cardinality.

Comment: so my assume is correct?

Comment: "Yes, just prove that if two sets are isomorphic and of finite cardinality, then they must have the same cardinality." -- Is that proof even necessary? For two groups to be isomorphic, it is necessary there exists a bijection between their underlying sets, which there does not if the cardinality differs between them. Or at the very least, the definition of (group) isomorphism I was always given was a function bijective on the underlying sets that is also a (group) homomorphism.

Comment: I mean clearly the results is not clear in his head. yeah it's not a 'proof', but asking why maybe?

Comment: [Haham](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/656891/haham) just check [Eevee's](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/597568/eevee-trainer) comment

Comment: i can say that 9 is relatively prive? in that question?